# Is constant system a Causal System?

Tags: signal-processing, control-theory

Is y(t) = 1 a causal system?

From the definition of causal systems , a causal system is a system where the output depends on past and current inputs.

Here the system doesn't depend on any input. So, is the system causal?

Comment: $H[y](t) = 1$ is not linear in the input signal $y$. but $H[y](t) = 0$ is and it is indeed a causal system.

Comment: What is H[y](t) ?

Comment: [a (linear) time-invariant system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory). the input is a signal $y(t), t \in \mathbb{R}$ and the output is a signal $H[y](t), t \in \mathbb{R}$ linear in the input $y$ : for any constants $a,b$ you get $H[ay_1+b y_2](t) = a H[y_1](t)+b H[y_2](t)$

Comment: Got the definition, but will H[y](t) = 1, although not linear, be causal?

Comment: forget non-linear systems for now, you'll see later. for non-linear systems causality (and also stability) is  much more complicated to define, but yes of course a non-linear system which doesn't depend on the input can be said to be causal (and stable) in some sense.